# Button asks for a URL then opens it?

Tags: android

I have a webView of a URL that works great but I also have a link that needs some info to load.

```
mylink.com/page.php?name=Stack
```

**How can I make a button ask for the user's name then put it in the link and load the webView?**

i.e: popup asks for a username (user puts the name as "Stack") and 'Stack' gets moved into the URL and loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I think this below can help you:

```
function goUrl() {
     var name = prompt("Please enter your name", "Place holder");
     console.log(name);
     window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + name;
 };
```

Function `prompt()` opens an popup from your browser with text field. The function returns what you have put in the text field so that you can use it anywhere you want eg. you can put the code above into a function that is being call on button click:

```
<button onclick="goUrl()">Click it!</button>
```

Comment: The only problem with using that is I do not have access to editing the code within the URL.

Comment: So you can firstly take the current url: var currentUrl = window.location.href; and edit it as you want.

Comment: I see now, I have to host it on my website, that's fine, thanks!